# Array of indexes to array of ranges

Tags: ruby, arrays, range

Ranges in ruby are pretty cool. 
I end up with arrays such as this:

```
geneRanges = [(234..25), (500..510), (1640..1653)]
```

And subsequently have to remove bits of them. For that I:

```
genePositions = geneRanges.collect {|range| range.entries }.flatten
=> [500, 501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506, 507, 508, 509, 510, 1640, 1641, 1642, 1643, 1644, 1645, 1646, 1647, 1648, 1649, 1650, 1651, 1652, 1653]
```

They get manipulated, so some numbers get excluded, and others may be added. I may end up with this:

```
[505, 506, 507, 600, 601, 602, 603, 1643, 1644, 1645, 1646, 1647, 1648, 1649, 1650, 1651, 1652, 1653, 1654]
```

How can I convert this back into a compact array of ranges? It seems that the inverse function should exist? I would expect it to return something like this:

```
[(505..507), (600..603), (1643..1654)]
```

Thanks!

Comment: more solutions on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360108

Comment: `(234..25)` is an invalid range. `(234..25).to_a
=> []`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

(New and improved.  Stays fresh in your refrigerator for up to two weeks!):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 20, 20, 4]

ranges = a.sort.uniq.inject([]) do |spans, n|
  if spans.empty? || spans.last.last != n - 1
    spans + [n..n]
  else
    spans[0..-2] + [spans.last.first..n]
  end
end

p ranges    # [1..4, 10..11, 20..20]
```

Comment: +1 Nice solution, however the value within the else should be `spans[0..-2] + [spans.last.first..n]` (Edited to fix)

Comment: Excellent - thanks! Check also Steve Weet's generalization and Mladen Jablanović's response further down!

Comment: Everyone in this place is smarter than I am, and @Mladen Jablanović consistently knocks them out of the park.

Answer (score 8):

Functional, not-very-readable solution:

```
(a[0,1]+a.each_cons(2).reject{|i,j| j-i==1}.flatten+a[-1,1]).
  each_slice(2).map{|i,j| i..j}
```

And a nice one:

```
class Array
  # splits array to sub-arrays wherever two adjacent elements satisfy a condition
  def split_by
    each_cons(2).inject([[first]]){|a, (i, j)|
      a.push([]) if yield(i, j)
      a.last.push j
      a
    }
  end

  # uses split_by to split array to subarrays with consecutive elements, then convert to range
  def to_range
    split_by{|i,j| j-i!=1}.map{|a| a.first..a.last}
  end
end

[505, 506, 507, 600, 1647, 1648, 1649, 1650, 1651, 1654].split_by{|i,j| j-i!=1}
#=> [[505, 506, 507], [600], [1647, 1648, 1649, 1650, 1651], [1654]]
[505, 506, 507, 600, 1647, 1648, 1649, 1650, 1651, 1654].to_range
#=> [505..507, 600..600, 1647..1651, 1654..1654]
```

Comment: SpaceBeforeModifierKeyword from RuboCop detected that there wasn't a space before `if` in `a.push([])if yield(i, j)`. I didn't know that was valid Ruby. O_o

Comment: Rubocop also suggests using `each_with_object` rather than `inject`.

Answer (score 5):

This is a straight crib of Wayne Conrads algorithm with a small tweak to make it work for other kinds of ranges, e.g. alphabetic

```
def array_to_ranges(a)
ranges = a.sort.uniq.inject([]) do |spans, n|
  if spans.empty? || spans.last.last.succ != n
    spans + [n..n]
  else
    spans[0..-2] + [spans.last.first..n]
  end
end
ranges
end

[
  [1..3, 10..11, 20..20, 4..4],
  [ "a".."c", "f".."h", "x".."z"],
  ["aa".."af"]
].each do |arange|
  p arange
  p array = arange.collect {|range| range.to_a}.flatten
  p array_to_ranges(array)
end
```

And the results of executing this are

```
[1..3, 10..11, 20..20, 4..4]
[1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 20, 4]
[1..4, 10..11, 20..20]
["a".."c", "f".."h", "x".."z"]
["a", "b", "c", "f", "g", "h", "x", "y", "z"]
["a".."c", "f".."h", "x".."z"]
["aa".."af"]
["aa", "ab", "ac", "ad", "ae", "af"]
["aa".."af"]
```

Comment: This is very cool. Imagine trying to do it in a language that didn't do duck-typing.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an answer (adapted from [this code](http://snippets.dzone.com/user/bsiggelkow)) that is more than twice as fast as the other code posted here. Further, only this answer and [the one by @Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728660/array-of-indexes-to-array-of-ranges/3730421#3730421) handle arrays of non-integers.

```
class Array
  def to_ranges
    return [] if empty?
    [].tap do |ranges|
      init,last = first
      each do |o|
        if last && o != last.succ
          ranges << (init..last)
          init = o
        end
        last = o
      end
      ranges << (init..last)
    end
  end
end
```

Here are the benchmark results:

```
                 user     system      total        real
steve        1.107000   0.000000   1.107000 (  1.106221)
wayne        1.092000   0.000000   1.092000 (  1.099220)
user229426   0.531000   0.000000   0.531000 (  0.523104)
mladen1      0.780000   0.000000   0.780000 (  0.774154)
mladen2      0.780000   0.000000   0.780000 (  0.792159)
phrogz       0.218000   0.000000   0.218000 (  0.220044)
```

*All benchmarked code was adapted to remove `sort.uniq` for a fair comparison.*

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen anything in the Ruby language that does that, but here is some code that might help you do it yourself:

http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4677

Answer (score 1):

```
ar=[505, 506, 507, 600, 1647, 1648, 1649, 1650, 1651, 1654]
def to_range(a)
  s=a[0]
  a.each_cons(2) do |a|
    if a[1]-a[0]!=1
        p s .. a[0]
        s=a[1]
    end
  end
  left=a.index(s)
  p a[left..-1][0]..a[left..-1][-1]
end
to_range(ar)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [505, 506, 507, 600, 601, 602, 603, 1643, 1644, 1645, 1646, 1647, 1648, 1649, 1650, 1651, 1652, 1653, 1654]
array.inject([]){ |a, e| a[-1] && a[-1].last && a[-1].last == e-1 ? a[-1] = (a[-1].first..e) : a << (e..e); a }
#=> [505..507, 600..603, 1643..1654]
```

and for not sorted arrays you can presort it:

```
array.sort!.uniq!
```

Comment: ~~You can't chain `sort!` !!!!~~ Sorry actually `sort!` does look like it is safe to chain for some reason. Most other mutating methods ending in `!` aren't (like gsub!, uniq!, etc) So I just cringe when I see anyone using the return value of any method ending in `!`

Comment: @JackCasey, of course you can chain any of listed methods (sort!, gsub! uniq!). But it could be meaningless in some cases

Comment: Sure, I meant it's a trap sometimes :)