# Find consecutive substring indexes

Tags: ruby, autocomplete

Given a search string and a result string (which is guaranteed to contain all letters of the search string, case-insensitive, in order), how can I most efficiently get an array of ranges representing the indices in the result string corresponding to the letters in the search string?

Desired output:

```
substrings( "word", "Microsoft Office Word 2007" )
#=> [ 17..20 ]

substrings( "word", "Network Setup Wizard" )
#=> [ 3..5, 19..19 ]
#=> [ 3..4, 18..19 ]   # Alternative, acceptable, less-desirable output

substrings( "word", "Watch Network Daemon" )
#=> [ 0..0, 10..11, 14..14 ]
```

This is for an autocomplete search box. Here's a screenshot from [a tool](http://colibri.leetspeak.org/) similar to [Quicksilver](http://qsapp.com/) that underlines letters as I'm looking to do. Note that--unlike my ideal output above--this screenshot does not prefer longer single matches.
[image: Screenshot of Colibri underlining letters in search results]

### Benchmark Results

Benchmarking the current working results shows that @tokland's regex-based answer is basically as fast as the StringScanner-based solutions I put forth, with less code:

```
               user     system      total        real
phrogz1    0.889000   0.062000   0.951000 (  0.944000)
phrogz2    0.920000   0.047000   0.967000 (  0.977000)
tokland    1.030000   0.000000   1.030000 (  1.035000)
```

Here is the benchmark test:

```
a=["Microsoft Office Word 2007","Network Setup Wizard","Watch Network Daemon"]
b=["FooBar","Foo Bar","For the Love of Big Cars"]
test = { a=>%w[ w wo wor word ], b=>%w[ f fo foo foobar fb fbr ] }
require 'benchmark'
Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
  %w[ phrogz1 phrogz2 tokland ].each{ |method|
    x.report(method){ test.each{ |words,terms|
      words.each{ |master| terms.each{ |term|
        2000.times{ send(method,term,master) }
      } }
    } }
  }
end
```

Comment: Update: I have created and released the [LiqrrdMetal](http://rubygems.org/gems/liqrrdmetal) gem using the knowledge from this thread. You can fork or contribute to [the project on GitHub](https://github.com/Phrogz/liqrrdmetal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have something to start with, how about that?

```
>> s = "word"
>> re = /#{s.chars.map{|c| "(#{c})" }.join(".*?")}/i # /(w).*?(o).*?(r).*?(d)/i/
>> match = "Watch Network Daemon".match(re)
=> #<MatchData "Watch Network D" 1:"W" 2:"o" 3:"r" 4:"D">
>> 1.upto(s.length).map { |idx| match.begin(idx) }
=> [0, 10, 11, 14]
```

And now you only have to [build the ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728660/array-of-indexes-to-array-of-ranges) (if you really need them, I guess the individual indexes are also ok).

Comment: Possible improvement: `re = /#{s.chars.map{|c| "(#{c})" }.join(".*?")}/i`. As shown by the benchmarks edited into the question, using the regex literal shaves 5% off the overall performance of this method (!). (I also changed the regex match to be non-greedy, in order to keep consecutive characters together.)

Comment: @Phrogz: it looks good, updated. I didn't know about String#chars, cool.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby's `Abbrev` module is a good starting point. It breaks down a string into a hash consisting of the unique keys that can identify the full word:

```
require 'abbrev'
require 'pp'

abbr = Abbrev::abbrev(['ruby'])
>> {"rub"=>"ruby", "ru"=>"ruby", "r"=>"ruby", "ruby"=>"ruby"}
```

For every keypress you can do a lookup and see if there's a match. I'd filter out all keys shorter than a certain length, to reduce the size of the hash.

The keys will also give you a quick set of words to look up the subword matches in your original string.

For fast lookups to see if there's a substring match:

```
regexps = Regexp.union(
  abbr.keys.sort.reverse.map{ |k|
    Regexp.new(
      Regexp.escape(k),
      Regexp::IGNORECASE
    )
  }
)
```

Note that it's escaping the patterns, which would allow characters to be entered, such as `?`, `*` or `.`, and be treated as literals, instead of special characters for regex, like they would normally be treated.

The result looks like:

```
/(?i-mx:ruby)|(?i-mx:rub)|(?i-mx:ru)|(?i-mx:r)/
```

Regexp's `match` will return information about what was found.

Because the `union` "ORs" the patterns, it will only find the first match, which will be the shortest occurrence in the string. To fix that reverse the sort.

That should give you a good start on what you want to do.

---

EDIT: Here's some code to directly answer the question. We've been busy at work so it's taken a couple days to get back this:

```
require 'abbrev'
require 'pp'

abbr = Abbrev::abbrev(['ruby'])
regexps = Regexp.union( abbr.keys.sort.reverse.map{ |k| Regexp.new( Regexp.escape(k), Regexp::IGNORECASE ) } )

target_str ='Ruby rocks, rub-a-dub-dub, RU there?'
str_offset = 0
offsets = []
loop do
  match_results = regexps.match(target_str, str_offset)
  break if (match_results.nil?)
  s, e = match_results.offset(0)
  offsets << [s, e - s]
  str_offset = 1 + s
end

pp offsets

>> [[0, 4], [5, 1], [12, 3], [27, 2], [33, 1]]
```

If you want ranges replace `offsets << [s, e - s]` with `offsets << [s .. e]` which will return:

```
>> [[0..4], [5..6], [12..15], [27..29], [33..34]]
```

Comment: This is good information, but doesn't satisfy my needs for matching inside of words. I'm working on a StringScanner-based solution now.

Comment: The regex should help for scanning inside words, or, the key values, which are subsets of the words. The "unionized" regex' flaw is that it is OR'd. You might want all hits, which you could do by looping over the keys, or by building a different big regex with captures so that `match` returned them all or `named_captures` could show the number of hits, if you used "named captures".

Comment: I think it's possible to get where you want to be. I did something similar the other day so I'll try to find my code and tweak it tonight.

Comment: If you choose to pursue this I'll be interested to see what you come up with. Though I've accepted @tokland's answer as the best for now, I'll re-benchmark and possibly change the answer based on any updates.

Comment: @Phrogz, I added an implementation based on how I'd do it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a late entrant that's making a move as it nears the finish line.

**code**

```
def substrings( search_str, result_str )
  search_chars = search_str.downcase.chars
  next_char = search_chars.shift
  result_str.downcase.each_char.with_index.take_while.with_object([]) do |(c,i),a|
    if next_char == c
      (a.empty? || i != a.last.last+1) ? a << (i..i) : a[-1]=(a.last.first..i)
      next_char = search_chars.shift
    end   
    next_char
  end
end
```

**demo**

```
substrings( "word", "Microsoft Office Word 2007" ) #=> [17..20]
substrings( "word", "Network Setup Wizard" )       #=> [3..5, 19..19]
substrings( "word", "Watch Network Daemon" )       #=> [0..0, 10..11, 14..14]
```

**benchmark**

```
              user     system      total        real
phrogz1   1.120000   0.000000   1.120000 (  1.123083)
cary      0.550000   0.000000   0.550000 (  0.550728)
```

Comment: This answer wins the award for longest number of chained enumerator methods I've ever witnessed. Well done! :) Note that this requires Ruby 2.0+ as written, where `String#chars` returns an array instead of an enumerator. With an explicit `to_a` call, it's "only" 25% faster than my answer (i.e. still the performance winner overall, just not as much as the benchmarks above show).

Comment: Glad you like it, froggie.  I have no idea why it did so well against the benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any built in methods that will really help with this, probably the best way is to go through each letter in the word you're searching for and build up the ranges manually. Your next best option would probably be to build a regex like in @tokland's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my implementation:

```
require 'strscan'
def substrings( search, master )
  [].tap do |ranges|
    scan = StringScanner.new(master)
    init = nil
    last = nil
    prev = nil
    search.chars.map do |c|
      return nil unless scan.scan_until /#{c}/i
      last = scan.pos-1
      if !init || (last-prev) > 1
        ranges << (init..prev) if init
        init = last
      end
      prev = last
    end
    ranges << (init..last)
  end
end
```

And here's a shorter version using another utility method (also needed by @tokland's answer):

```
require 'strscan'
def substrings( search, master )
  s = StringScanner.new(master)
  search.chars.map do |c|
    return nil unless s.scan_until(/#{c}/i)
    s.pos - 1
  end.to_ranges
end

class Array
  def to_ranges
    return [] if empty?
    [].tap do |ranges|
      init,last = first
      each do |o|
        if last && o != last.succ
          ranges << (init..last)
          init = o
        end
        last = o
      end
      ranges << (init..last)
    end
  end
end
```