# How do I summarize array of integers as an array of ranges?

Tags: ruby, arrays, algorithm, functional-programming, range

I'd like to take input such as:

```
[1,2,4,5,6,7,9,13]
```

and turn it into something like the following:

```
[[1,2],[4,7],[9,9],[13,13]]
```

Each sub-array represents a range of integers.

Comment: Are you asking if there is code to do this already? Are you asking because you're trying to roll your own and having trouble implementing it?

Comment: I'm rolling my own.  Seems there are always interesting ways to implement this kind of thing in Ruby.

Comment: By which conditions are the ranges supposed to be built?

Comment: A continuous integer sequence in the array should compose a "range" which is really just an array with the start and end.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array of indexes to array of ranges](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728660/array-of-indexes-to-array-of-ranges)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Functional approach using [Enumerable#chunk](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk):

```
ranges = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 13]
  .enum_for(:chunk) # .chunk for Ruby >= 2.4
  .with_index { |x, idx| x - idx }
  .map { |_diff, group| [group.first, group.last] }

#=> [[1, 2], [4, 7], [9, 9], [13, 13]]
```

How it works: once indexed, consecutive elements in the array have the same `x - idx`, so we use that value to chunk (grouping of consecutive items) the input array. Finally we just need to take the first and last elements of each group to build the pairs.

Comment: This looks really nice. Totally forgot about the new chunk method.

Comment: And to take it one more step, `.map{ |min,max| min == max ? min : min .. max }` will result in: `[1..2, 4..7, 9, 13]`.

Comment: Or, change `[pairs.first[0], pairs.last[0]]` to
`pairs.first[0] .. pairs.last[0]` to get ranges in all positions: `[1..2, 4..7, 9..9, 13..13]`.

Comment: In Ruby 2.4, the `enum_for` will [no longer be necessary](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/69846644d25b0a40ab787b150716a5d17e63f6a8).

Comment: I also posted an even easier solution with `chunk_while`

Answer (score 5):

This is almost straight from the [enumerable#slice_before](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before) method documentation:

```
ar = [1,2,4,5,6,7,9,13]
prev = ar[0]
ar.slice_before{|e|prev,prev2 = e,prev; prev2.succ != e}.map{|a|a.first..a.last}
#=> [1..2, 4..7, 9..9, 13..13]
```

This should work with characters, dates, anything with a `.succ` method.

Answer (score 5):

An even easier solution than [@tokland's very nice one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8621810/8279) is using [`chunk_while`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while):

```
xs.chunk_while { |a, b| a + 1 == b }.map do |seq|
  [seq.first, seq.last]
end
```

*Note*: `chunk_while` was introduced in Ruby 2.3

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, well, it's not [tokland's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188031/tokland) masterpiece, but I think it may be a good straightforward solution...

```
[1,2,4,5,6,7,9,13].inject([]) do |m, v|
  if m.last.to_a.last == v.pred
    m[-1][-1] = v
  else
    m << [v, v]
  end
  m
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach

```
def summarize(x)
  x.inject([]) do |acc, value|
    if acc.last && acc.last[1] + 1 == value
      acc.last[1] = value
      acc
    else
      acc << [value,value]
    end
  end
end
```

Similar to Larsenal's method but using inject to manage the boring stuff.