# Find overlaps in array of ranges and build a new array with new chunked ranges

Tags: javascript, ruby, arrays, range

Ideally, I'd like a solution in Ruby or Javascript. Arrays instead of ranges in javascript would be fine.

I'd like input such as:

```
    [0..301, 230..268, 242..364, 574..579, 587..593]
```

or

```
    [0,301, 230,268, 242,364, 574,579, 587,593]
```

And turn it into something like:

```
    [0..230, 230..242, 242..268, 268..301, 301..364, 574..579, 587..593]
```

or

```
    [[0,230], [230,242, [242,268], [268,301], [301,364], [574,579, [587,593]]
```

Any help would be great. This sort of helps but not fully because it gives the full range instead of the chunked ranges, [How do I summarize array of integers as an array of ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621733/how-do-i-summarize-array-of-integers-as-an-array-of-ranges).

Comment: Javascript doesn't have ranges like you've specified.  What input/output format do you want if it's javascript?

Comment: Arrays for javascript like [[0,230],[230,242]...] would be fine. My bad, missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a ruby solution:

```
ranges = [0..301, 230..268, 242..364, 574..579, 587..593]
endpoints = ranges.map{|r| [r.first, r.last]}.flatten.sort
values = ranges.map{|r| r.to_a}.reduce(:+)

new_ranges = []
endpoints.reduce do |x, y|
    r = Range.new(x,y);
    new_ranges << r if r.all?{|v| values.include? v}
    y
end

puts new_ranges

#0..230
#230..242
#242..268
#268..301
#301..364
#574..579
#587..593
```

Comment: This is perfect! Very, very nice Ruby solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Javascript solution:

```
(function (inp) {
    var out = [];

    inp.reduce(function (a,b) {
        return a.concat(b);
    }).sort().forEach(function(v,k, flat) {
        if(!k) return;
        out.push([flat[k-1], v]);
    });

    console.log(out);
})([[0,301], [230,268], [242,364], [574,579], [587,593]]);
```

This solution will only work with browsers that support Javascript 1.8. I had to adapt your input to be Javascript compatible, since as jfriend00 said, Javascript doesn't have ranges.

Here is the output:

```
[ [ 0, 230 ],
  [ 230, 242 ],
  [ 242, 268 ],
  [ 268, 301 ],
  [ 301, 364 ],
  [ 364, 574 ],
  [ 574, 579 ],
  [ 579, 587 ],
  [ 587, 593 ] ]
```

Comment: That doesn't look like the output that the question asked for.

Comment: This is very close, but not 100% what I need yet.

Comment: @jfriend00 Good call. I fixed it up.

Comment: Almost there...the output shouldn't have [364,574] and [579,587] because [574, 579] and [587,593] don't have any overlapping in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby solution.

```
def f(a)
  a.map! {|r| [r.first, r.last ] }.sort!

  segs = [a.shift]
  a.each {|s, e|
    if segs.last.last < s
      segs << [s, e]
    else
      segs.last.concat [s, e]
      segs.last.sort!
    end
  }
  segs.map {|seg|
    seg.each_cons(2).map { |s, e| (s..e) }
  }.flatten
end

puts f([0..301, 230..268, 242..364, 574..579, 587..593])

#0..230
#230..242
#242..268
#268..301
#301..364
#574..579
#587..593
```