# Turn an array into keys for hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

How do I turn an Array into a Hash with values of `0` without an `each` loop.

For example, given this array:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I want to get this hash:

```
{"1"=>0, "2"=>0, "3"=>0, "4"=>0}
```

Comment: Why the constraint of not using `each`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a fan of simple, and I can never remember exactly how crazy things `#inject` or Hash constructor arguments work.

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
hash = {}

array.each do |obj|
  hash[obj.to_s] = 0
end

puts hash.inspect # {"1"=>0, "2"=>0, "3"=>0, "4"=>0}
```

Comment: I appreciate everyone's response, but I like this answer the best. Thanks!

Comment: @TonyHassan Interesting that you accepted this even though you *specifically* requested no use of `each`.

Comment: "simple" is a subjective concept so I won't go there. But not using a programming language capabilities to its full, that I cannot understand. Why write four lines when a single perfectly idiomatic line will do? granted, this is easier to understand for a novice with an imperative background (or no background), but at some point or another a Ruby programmer will have to learn some functional principles.

Comment: Andrew that is correct. But once I saw it I changed my mind. I try to be flexible. :)

Answer (score 8):

The standard approach is [Hash[...]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html):

```
Hash[xs.map { |x| [x.to_s, 0] }]
```

Or `Enumerable#mash` if you happen to use Facets. I cannot think of something more concise and declarative:

```
xs.mash { |x| [x.to_s, 0] }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
array.inject({}) { | a, e | a[e.to_s] = 0; a }
```

or in a more clean way (thanks to [tokland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188031/tokland), see the discussion in the comments)

```
array.inject({}) { | a, e | a.update(e.to_s => 0) }
```

Comment: `a.each_with_object({}) { |e, a| a[e.to_s] = 0 }` might be a better choice since you're not really injecting.

Comment: @mu: why is not injecting? it looks a standard fold, only that it could be indeed written with a single expression in the block: `array.inject({}) { |acc, x| acc.update(x.to_s => 0) }` (using update for efficiency, pure functional would be a merge)

Comment: @tokland: The `; a` is the smelly part of this use of `inject`, the feedback is forced through a "dummy" return value from the block so the block's structure is { do_what_I_really_want_to_do; oh_yeah_this_is_inject_so_return_a }`. So `inject` is being used more like a general purpose iterator than an injection. I'd probably go with `acc.merge!(x.to_s => 0)` (for the same reason you'd use `update`) if I wanted to use `inject`. Maybe my problem with that form of `inject` is that you have to look twice to make sure the block's return value is correct.

Comment: BTW, one of those upvotes is mine so read my first comment as a suggestion rather than a criticism.

Comment: @mu: definitely, I agree, I also dislike to see this in a `inject` block when folding is an abstraction that comes from the functional world. You can use it imperatively, yeah, but it's not great to see.

Comment: @tokland In addition to what mu said, `inject` returning an object of equal dimension as the initial object (like here where a one-dim array becomes a one-dim hash) always seemed wrong to me. But perhaps I take `inject`'s synonym `reduce` too literally.

Comment: @Andrew: `inject` and `reduce` are completely equivalent, as you know `inject` is just a "funny" name that comes from Smalltalk's heritage. Regarding the "equal dimension" problem, I think you are looking at it wrong. Here `inject` takes a list of items (an array) to return an accumulated value (a hash) with an initial value of that accumulated type (a hash), that's exactly what a fold is. In Haskell terms: `[a]#inject :: b -> (b -> a -> b) -> b`. These types hold in the snippet. The problem with this approach: Ruby has `Hash[...]` (like Python has `dict`), so there's no need to do that.

Comment: @tokland I never said `inject` and `reduce` are different, and I'm well aware that folding *can* take a data-structure of n dimension and produce one of that same n dimension. I'm just saying that, in that case, you're not "reducing" anything, which always made it seem sort of odd—if you happen to use that name (`reduce`) for the operation—since your input and output are of the same "size".

Comment: @Andrew. Oh, ok, sorry for the misunderstanding. The name is indeed confusing some times (inject even more than reduce for me. `foldl` is more aseptic :-)).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, in reality, I'd use `each_with_object`, but posting this since it's more fun.

```
ary = *1..4

hash = Hash[ary.zip ary.dup.fill 0]

hash # => {1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0}
```