# ArgumentError - tried to call lazy take_while without a block

Tags: ruby, lazy-sequences

Imagine, that there are M large text files each with N lines, that are indexed from 1 to M*N. My goal is to get either all lines after the index X or just last 10 of them if X isn't provided. I could do an external `if` to split these two formulas, but I want to put `? :` deep inside such as:

```
    Dir.glob("logs/*").reverse.lazy.flat_map{ |f|
        File.readlines(f).reverse.map{ |str| str.split(" ", 2) }
    }.take_while.with_index{ |(i, str), n|
        x ? (i.to_i >= x) : (n < 10)
    }.to_a.reverse
```

But I get:

> ArgumentError - tried to call lazy take_while without a block:`

while according to answers such as: [Grouping consecutive numbers in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23841206/322020)
chaining `.take_while.with_index` should be possible.

Do I do something wrong and don't see the bug or does `.lazy` really just lack some functionality and I have to wait for some patch in future?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I just have to switch `.take_while.with_index` to `.with_index.take_while`.