# Ruby group integer array to range array

Tags: arrays, ruby, collections, range

Is there an elegant way to group an integer array to a range array in Ruby?

```
range1 = [*39..45]
#=> [39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45]

range2 = [*49..52]
#=> [49, 50, 51, 52]

range = range1 + range2
#=> [39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 49, 50, 51, 52]

range.build_ranges
#=> [39..45, 49..52]
```

Comment: Also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23840815/grouping-consecutive-numbers-in-an-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Given that the original array is already sorted and uniqued:

```
[39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 49, 50, 51, 52]
.chunk_while{|i, j| i.next == j}
.map{|a| a.first..a.last}
# => [39..45, 49..52]
```